# Python parsing set-cookie header

Tags: python, http, cookies

In PHP I send one cookie with secure and http only flags, and other without

```
setcookie("c2","value");
setcookie("c1","value", 0, "/", "", true, true);
```

It produces header

```
Set-Cookie: c2=value, c1=value; path=/; secure; httponly
```

In firebug I can see, this is OK (c1 secure flag is True, c2 is False)

I want to get which one of them is not using secure flag
My python code:

```
cookies = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
cookies.load(headers['set-cookie'])
print cookies

Output:
Set-Cookie: c1=value; Path=/\\r\\nSet-Cookie: c2=value
```

headers['set-cookie'] **does** contain original set-cookie header, it's ok
According to python documentation printing(handling as string) SimpleCookie instance should create set-cookie header. Point is, that something is missing after parsing original header.
Morsels also contains wrong values (secure and http only).

Is this some kind of misconfiguration or it's a bug in python library ?
Thanks :)

Comment: I ended up splitting cookies by ^([^"]|"[^"]*")*?(,) regex. But more pythonic solution would be appriciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late but saw your question and thought you may still need help.
The code I use to read a cookie is:

```
import Cookie,os
def getCookieData():
    try:
        cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"])
        session = cookie['usrSession'].value
        return session
    except (Cookie.CookieError, KeyError):
        return None
```

My cookie string its something along the lines of:

```
Cookie: usrSession=12345
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You are parsing the cookie header sent with an HTTP request.  But the question is about how to parse the Set-Cookie header returned with an HTTP response.